# How to handle form files with Phoenix LiveView?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm using Phoenix LiveView to build a form with an image (avatar).

I know that Phoenix LiveView does't support files yet, so, what approximation can I use?

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/JonRowe/phoenix_live_view_dropzone.
This will help you if you wish to upload file(s) in the background of your Live View to a pre authenticated resource.